# nginx reverse proxy on docker - problem with setup custom ip for each domain

Tags: docker, nginx

I an have nginx reverse proxy running in a docker container. On the host server I have a service failover ip.

I want set for each domain on the nginx server to a  custom ip, beacause at the moment all domains are using the main ip of my server.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would argue that what you have right now is the most common configuration: your reverse proxy (nginx/traefik/haproxy/etc) listens on a single address and then routing requests to appropriate backend hosts by name. Configuring a separate external ip for each domain adds a level of complexity that may not be necessary.

However, if you really want to do that, start by adding multiple ip addresses to your host. For example, on my host, I have:

```
$ ip addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    altname eno2
    altname enp0s31f6
    inet 192.168.1.200/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.201/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.202/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.175/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 55548sec preferred_lft 55548sec
```

I have a sample configuration in which I am running nginx as the frontend with two different backends (named `backend1` and `backend2`).

I'm going to configure nginx so that connections to `192.168.1.201` go to `backend1` and connections to `192.168.1.202` go to `backend2`. We do that by:

1. Having nginx listen on multiple ports (one port for each backend), and then
2. Publishing these ports on different ip addresses

We start with the `nginx` configuration:

```
server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend1/;
    }
}

server {
    listen       8001;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend2/;
    }
}
```

This maps connections on port 8000 to `backend1` and connections on port 8001 to `backend2`. To expose these on port 80 on different host addresses, we can create a `docker-compose.yaml` like this:

```
services:
  frontend:
    image: docker.io/nginx:mainline
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 192.168.1.201:80:8000
      - 192.168.1.202:80:8001

  backend1:
    image: docker.io/containous/whoami:latest

  backend2:
    image: docker.io/containous/whoami:latest
```

This means that connections to `http://192.168.1.201` will get mapped to port 8000, and hence to `backend1`, while connections to `http://192.168.1.202` will get mapped to port 8001, and hence to `backend2`.

---

After running `docker-compose up`, I can confirm this configuration:

```
$ curl -s 192.168.1.201 | grep Host:
Host: backend1
$ curl -s 192.168.1.202 | grep Host:
Host: backend2
```